Iteratively source a value from a dictionary
I have a data set where I know a limited number of values and based on other values in a data set I can figure out what the subsequent values are.  I could do this with a huge if function, but I know long ago someone (in a job with code I no longer have access to) showed me how to source these values from a dictionary using lambda and apply.
I need to create this iteratively because whilst I can figure out a value post "Five_Zero", after that I have nothing to go on and need the prior value to know the next.
This is what my starting data looks like.

I need to use a combination of WonLost, OnServeCorrected, and Score_Shift and source that from a list of possibles and return a value.  This returns an error.  I do not use lambda a lot and do not understand it well - I have not been able to find examples of how to replicate this.
This is the error I've received:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "mappingapplying.py", line 30, in 
touch3["Score"][i] = touch3.var.apply(lambda x:x[d])
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'apply'
Indenting may be off as the code didn't copy cleanly.
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


data = [[1, "Won", 1, "Five", "Zero"],
    [2, "Lost", 1, "",""],
    [3, "Lost", 1, "",""],
    [4, "Lost", 0, "Five","Zero"],
    [5, "Lost", 0, "",""],
    [6, "Won", 0, "",""]]
touch3 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ["Seconds", "WonLost", "OnServeCorrected", "S_Score", "R_Score"])
touch3["Score"] = touch3.S_Score + "_" + touch3.R_Score
touch3["Score_Shift"] = touch3.Score.shift(1)


d = [['Won_0_Five_Zero', "Five_Five"],
 ['Won_1_Five_Zero', "Three_Zero"],
 ['Lost_0_Five_Zero', "Three_Zero"],
 ['Lost_1_Five_Zero', "Five_Five"],
 ['Won_0_Five_Five', "Five_Three"], 
 ['Lost_0_Five_Five', "Three_Five"], 
 ['Won_1_Five_Five', "Three_Five"], 
 ['Lost_1_Five_Five', "Five_Three"]]

for i in range(len(touch3.Seconds)):
    if touch3.Score[i] not in (["Five_Zero", "Zero_Five"]):
       touch3["var"] = touch3.WonLost[i] + "_" + str(touch3.OnServeCorrected[i]) + "_" + touch3.Score_Shift[i]
    
       touch3["Score"][i] = touch3.var.apply(lambda x:x[d])
else:
    touch3.Score[i] = touch3.Score[i]

Expected output should be:


Can you provide the exact expected output? Also, explicitly state what is the input and where your attempts starts

Thanks for the help. Updated to include the expected output.
I don't understand the other questions.  This is my own code.  I always have a start point of Five_Zero or Zero_Five, and from that it takes the values from "WonLost, OnServeCorrected and ScoreShift" to figure out what the next score should be.
if you need more, can you tell me more specifically what you need?

" This returns an error." - What does this mean? At the very least you should show a complete error message. But please keep in mind that we don't "find the bug" for you here - it's your responsibility before posting to apply standard debugging techniques and produce a proper [mre]. You also need to decide what you're asking: are you trying to understand a specific error or are you trying to find out how to accomplish a specific task?

" after that I have nothing to go on and need the prior value to know the next." - Have you heard of the shift method of DataFrame?

I have added the error message.
I am asking for how to accomplish a specific task.  Ie how to iteratively map / apply  an output, based on a series of inputs.
I have tried something but it is returning an error and I believe its because I am using map and apply wrong, but do not understand how I should use it.  I have looked for examples to replicate but cannot find them.  Hence I come to you.

I use shift here already to create an input into the logic that should determine the output.  The use of shift does not solve my issue, as it informs what the follow up value can be but is not enough to simply shift the value down

I am not sure I understood correctly, but it seems you want to fill in the values in the column Score based on a lookup-table d matching the score from the previous row.
If that is the case, it could be very simple and no lambdas or applies are needed. Just change your lookup table to a dict, iterate over your data and fill in your value on each row using the previous row index.
d = {
    ('Won', 0, 'Five_Zero'): "Five_Five",
    ('Won', 1, 'Five_Zero'): "Three_Zero",
    ('Lost', 0, 'Five_Zero'): "Three_Zero",
    ('Lost', 1, 'Five_Zero'): "Five_Five",
    ('Won', 0, 'Five_Five'): "Five_Three",
    ('Lost', 0, 'Five_Five'): "Three_Five",
    ('Won', 1, 'Five_Five'): "Three_Five",
    ('Lost', 1, 'Five_Five'): "Five_Three",
}

for i in range(len(touch3.Seconds)):
    if touch3.Score[i] not in (["Five_Zero", "Zero_Five"]):
       touch3.Score[i] = d.get((touch3.WonLost[i], touch3.OnServeCorrected[i], touch3.Score[i-1]),"_")



Yep this works perfectly.  Thank you.  Challenge is not knowing the functions and ways to achieve things.  I had started creating highly nested ifs and this will save me a lot of time and I expect processing power.  Thank you
